# Detecting the distance of my dog to the food bowl

Tags: rf, msp430, rfid, range-detector

When one of my dogs sneaks to another dog's food bowl, I want to be notified so I can stop it. I have EZ430-RF2500 (msp430) development kit. Is it suitable for such project?
 I also have Arduino so I could use rfid tag but is the detection distance sufficient? 
I want to be notified when the distance is ~15-20cm. 
Or what alternatives exist? And are they risky for the health of the animals? You can explain as if explaining to an idiot.

Comment: Are the dogs chipped or can you put the RFID tag in the dog collar? If so, you could position the reader where it would detect the dog in the normal eating position and slide a cover from the bowl. (I'm thinking of a sheet of metal / plastic on drawer slides a cm or two over the bowl. Poll the RFID tag every 5s, open if s/he's there, close if s/he's not.

Comment: @transistor - This is the perfect solution. Instead of preventing the wrong dog eating from the bowl you permit the correct dog access to the bowl. Nice solution with positive verification with RFID. One could even make the dog's positoning at the bowl be regulated to some degree by setting the bowl and slide door back in a sort of an alcove structure. This could even prevent two dogs from standing side by side at the bowl. Such system could also keep the cats out of the dog's food.

Comment: Ok inspired by you and made a prototype http://imgur.com/a/6cNda
Except that instead of NFC sticker in the photo, it will be rfid.

Comment: @transistor - are common hobbyist readers sensitive enough to read a tag >10cm away? If not, it might be hard to position the reader where it'll consistently sense the tag.

Comment: @curtis, I don't know. I looked at the data sheet for the EZ430-RF2500 but I couldn't easily find that information.

Comment: some cat owners made a version with rfid reader and cd-rom drive as a lid. http://www.instructables.com/id/RFID-pet-feeder/
i can modify for my tall dog maybe. another one for dogs http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-RFID-pet-food-access-control-system/
looks like rfid is good choice, but the trick might be the antenna design.